# Forbidden 403 Using Django CAS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, authentication, cas

I'm attempting to implement CAS into a Django Application, I'm using django-cas-ng for my implementation, I've gotten to a point where I'm able to go to https://***myproject***/accounts/login and successfully login to CAS, but immediately upon logging in, I'm met with a **Forbidden 403** page.

The URL returned upon a logon is: https://***myproject***/accounts/login?next=%2F&ticket=***ticket***.

I'm unable to find any documentation on how to proceed next, I synced (makemigrations && migrate for my Django version), and assured that my settings.py had the proper configuration. I'm not sure where to proceed from here, any help is appreciated greatly!